# phpword not able to replace existing image in the docx file

Tags: php, phpword

I am trying to replace existing image in the word file using below code. when I save the output file was having old image as it is.

I open the word file and paste the 1.png image then I try to replace 1.png with 2.jpg but it is not doing anything. I have tried to see many solutions but I do not found any permanent good solution.

```
$templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor($source_file);
$image_path = '2.jpg';
$templateProcessor->setImageValue('1.png', '2.jpg');
$templateProcessor->saveAs('output.docx');
```

version  "phpoffice/phpword": "^0.18.3"

Comment: wait, replacing an image on a document (`docx`) or a template (`dotm`)?

Comment: to clarify my question, if the image is not added through a template, trying to replace the image using the template is an act of futility. if its a document made without template, you have to dig the entire element tree, find the image, replace it. alternatively, open the zip, find the image (usually in `\word\media` folder), then replace it. do remember each approach have their own gotchas.

Comment: @BagusTesa i am sorry i do not exactly understood your answer. can you please explain me in more detail ? how can i add image in existing word template so it can be easily replaced through my code ? Thanks